# Backspace in PyCharm Live Template

Tags: pycharm, live-templates

I'm trying to type `l` then type `tab` and then have my PyCharm Live Template insert `&lt;`. The problem I'm having is that there needs to be a space before `l` in order for me to be able to use the `l` "Abbreviation". So is there a variable expression that will delete that space for me? `\b` didn't work for me. Thanks for your help.

Dusty

Comment: I doubt you can, but why would you want to do something like this?

Comment: I would like type this and hit tab: `example text l`. If I type `example textl` and then hit tab, `textl`is not my "Abbreviation"

Comment: Perhaps groovy has that capability?  I don't know it very well, but I had to learn how to tap into groovy in order to make a string full caps that was not natively supported in the exposed live template functions.  `groovyScript(_1.toUpperCase())`

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such possibility. As an alternative, you can record the typing of &lt; as a macro (Edit | Macros) and then assign a keyboard shortcut to that macro (Settings | Keymap | Macros).